# Fur/Hair Flickering Issues

Tags: hair

This is something I've been struggling on for a good few days now - so if anyone can help me I would incredibly grateful!

[image: Creature w/ Fur]

Basically, I'm working on creature design for a film I'm making. Part of the creature would have hair - so I've been working out how to realistically animate it using the hair dynamics. However, I've found that the hair (to a greater degree or another) has an annoying property when animated in that it seems to 'strobe' or flicker when rendered.

This is an example of some massive flickering (apologies for the dodgy armature, but I'm halfway through setting up my mocap and the arms in this session refused to behave properly): [massively flickering hair.](https://youtu.be/dGVumufsy9Y)

I reduced the number of hairs which seemed to help a bit - this one is a mix of short, non-animated hairs and a few longer animated hairs: [lesser flickering hair.](https://youtu.be/fCsvjW8v3sI)

To me, it seems the thicker the hair and more dynamic it is (lower stiffness, higher mass &tc) the more flicker I'm getting. I'm using two hair BSDF shaders with a high (.9) roughness into a mix. These vids are rendered with about 30 samples (path tracing) but the issues also is exhibited with 500 samples. In the second video I'm using 30 interpolated children with 150 hairs.

[image: Material Nodes]

I've been trying various tips mentioned in other posts (though I'm not sure how to change the UV coordinates for a hair material as mentioned here: [How do I prevent hair flickering in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-prevent-hair-flickering-in-cycles)).

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction regarding either the above post or other things to try? Let me know if you need anything more from me!